# Animate path (line) from last known point to new added point (d3)

Tags: javascript, graphics, svg, d3.js, plot

I'm still learning to program and I'm currently trying out the d3 library.

So far I'm pretty happy with the result. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zxNc4/1/)

**Q:** If you check out the link (or part of the code under this question) you should try to plot a point. This is only possible on the x-axis ticks. You'll see it animates but it's not exactly what I want. I just want it to animate the newly added line. I have checked out .enter() and .append() but I was getting errors. I might be doing something wrong.

```
function lines(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y+h;
}

var lineArray = [{x: 0, y: h}, {x: 1, y: h}];
var lineArrayPrevious = lineArray[lineArray.length -1].x;
var d3line = d3.svg.line()
                  .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
                  .y(function(d) { return d.y; })
                  .interpolate("monotone");


var path = svg.append("path").attr("d", d3line(lineArray)).attr("class", "line");

canPlot = true;

function plot() {
 var m = d3.mouse(this);

 if (m[0]-20 > lineArray[lineArray.length - 1].x)  {
   var lineX = lineArray.push(new lines(m[0], m[1]));

   svg.selectAll("path")
      .data(lineArray)
      .attr("d", d3line(lineArray));

   var point = svg.append("circle")
                  .attr("cx", function(d, i) { return m[0]; })
                  .attr("cy", function(d, i) { return m[1]+h; })
                  .attr("r", 0).transition().delay(150).attr("r", 6);


   var totalLength = path.node().getTotalLength();
   console.log();
   path.attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength + " " + totalLength)
       .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength)
       .transition().duration(700).ease("linear").attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0).delay(200);

   canPlot = true;
 } else { console.log("error"); canPlot = false; }
}
```

Excuse my bad code, I'm learning and will clean it up eventually.

**Q2:** How hard would it be to make a circle that follows the mouse's y-position and moves on the ticks when you get near one?

**Q3:** If we solve my first question, would it be easy to get the lines to animate/update automatically when we do question 2?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For Q1 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20318833/in-d3-js-is-there-a-way-to-add-on-to-a-line-one-point-at-a-time-using-d3-trans/20319506

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't seem to work for me. How do you plot a point?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff you can only plot on the grey lines. Thanks for checking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've updated your jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zxNc4/2/) to include the points that you're asking for.

Regarding question 1, I've changed the way the line is drawn such that it can be interpolated from the previous to the current point in a transition. The relevant code is this.

```
svg.select("path.line")
      .attr("d", d3line(lineArray))
      .transition().duration(700)
      .attrTween('d', pathTween)
      .each("end", function() {
           var lineX = lineArray.push(new lines(m[0], m[1]));
      });

   var last = lineArray[lineArray.length-1];

   function pathTween() {
        var xi = d3.interpolate(last.x, m[0]),
            yi = d3.interpolate(last.y, m[1] + h);
        return function(t) {
            return d3line(lineArray.concat([{x: xi(t), y: yi(t)}]));
        };
   }
```

Note that the new data point is only added to the array of points once the transition finishes.

Regarding your second question, this is taken care of by attaching handlers to all tick marks and append a marker on mouse over:

```
d3.selectAll(".xaxis > .tick").on("mouseenter", mousein)
 .on("mousemove", mousemove)
 .on("mouseleave", mouseout);

function mousein() {
  svg.append("circle").attr("class", "marker").attr("r", 3)
   .attr("pointer-events", "none");
}

function mousemove() {
  d3.select("circle.marker")
    .attr("transform", d3.select(this).attr("transform"))
    .attr("cy", d3.mouse(this)[1] + h);
}

function mouseout() {
  d3.select("circle.marker").remove();
}
```

Comment: Wow! Amazing man! I will keep re-reading your code until I got it 100%. I appreciate your help. It works perfectly and I wish I could give you more points. You also commented on my previous question. From reading your profile I got you're the d3 guru... Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome. Note that you could do the animation with your previous method (hacking the dasharray of the path) as well, but it would require some mental gymnastics and the D3 way is definitely to use interpolators as I have. You can of course make it prettier by creating a single custom interpolator for both coordinates instead of two separate ones :)